# Nested and recursive JSON input handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am building a REST API using rails and I have a few controllers that accept nested and recursive JSON, for example, when doing a PUT on /taxonomies/:id.json you can pass something like:

```
{
  "names":[
    "brands",
    "secondary_brands"
  ],
  "taxonomy_data":{
    "some":"data"
  },
  "terms":[
    {
      "slug":"apple",
      "data":{
        "value":"Apple California"
      },
      "overridable_data":{
        "weight":0.5
      },
      "term_data":{
        "description":{
          "en":"Apple makes the iPhone"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "slug":"microsoft",
      "data":{
        "value":"Microsoft Inc"
      },
      "overridable_data":{
        "weight":0.5
      },
      "term_data":{
        "description":{
          "en":"Microsoft makes windows"
        }
      },
      "children":[
        {
          "data":{
            "value":"Xbox"
          },
          "overridable_data":{
            "weight":0.5
          },
          "term_data":{
            "description":{
              "en":"Xbox one is bad"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "slug":"hp",
      "data":{
        "value":"HP Inc"
      },
      "overridable_data":{
        "weight":0.5
      },
      "term_data":{
        "description":{
          "en":"HP makes atomic clocks"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now, I put the following code in my model:

```
class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many                            :terms,
                                      -> {order(:id)}


  def update_terms(params)

    existing_term_ids = terms.map &:id

    create_term = lambda do |term_params, parent=nil|
      t = terms.find_by(:id => term_params[:id]) if term_params[:id]
      t ||= terms.build
      t.attributes = term_params.slice(:slug, :data, :overridable_data, :term_data)
      t.parent = parent
      t.save
      existing_term_ids.delete(t.id)

      if term_params.has_key?(:children)
        term_params[:children].each do |child_params|
          create_term.call(child_params, t)
        end
      end

    end

    params.each do |term_params|
      create_term.call(term_params)
    end

    terms.where(:id => existing_term_ids).destroy_all
    save
  end
end
```

This version (rapidly written to test rails 4) uses slice to filter parameters because attr_accessible is gone.

This makes me wonder if this kind of code should be in the model or the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this acticle: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

My opinion, you should do the service in this case, something like this:

```
# app/services/recursive_update.rb
class RecursiveUpdate
  def initalize(source)
    @source = source
  end

  def update(params)
    # your code here
  end

  def create_term(term_params, parent=nil)
    #....
  end

  def permitted_params
    #....
  end

  def save
    @source.save
  end
end
```

in the controller:

```
updater = RecurciveUpdate.new @model
updater.update params
update.save
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like that. I am more and more using those "non rails class" as my apps grow. The usual theory is to do fat models, but a lot of code could be modularized in this way and pulled out of models.